# best instanceof workaround for c++

Tags: c++, virtual, instanceof, dynamic-cast

I heard about the options with `dynamic_cast` & rtti(but costs a lot) or virtual functions , but I'm not sure which is the best!

Lets say I have Following Example

I have a parent class `Human` with 2 child classes `Man` and `Woman`.

`Human` ofc provides some standard methods.
But lets say `Woman` has different and more methods than `Man`.

Why I need to know the instance of a object?
Lets say i have function which only allows humans as parameter.
So the parameter could be a man or woman.
But for further actions I need to know if the Human object is actually a `Man` or `Woman`, cast it to one of them both.

I think in this case it isn't a good idea to use virtual functions because the child class have a different amount of methods?!

Comment: Without a specific example, it will be hard to give an opinion on this. But with regards to what you are generically talking about, virtual functions seem like a fine design choice.

Comment: This is a contrived question without use or context. The contrived answer is that you should simply use `dynamic_cast` and not worry about the contrived costs.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that `dynamic_cast` is less efficient than `instanceof` in Java (or whatever other language you're talking about)?

Comment: In each post, I read that dynamic_cast comes with a cost. I didn't tested it

Comment: It does. You think `instanceof` doesn't? ;-)

Comment: well i have no idea :>
performance is actually really important, because I'm workin on a game project. But I think using virtual isn't the solution in this case

Comment: Add the Women methods to the Human class, but have them do nothing in the Human class.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct - if you find yourself needing casting or rtti, that's a good sign that maybe you need to rethink your design.

But the whole idea of "inheritance" is that you can define a class "man" with specialized methods and data that pertain only to "males", a different class "woman" with her own specialized data and methods ... and a parent class "human" for those classes a methods they have in common.

Furthermore, a click should generally use the "human" class (it generally shouldn't care if the instance happens to be a "man" or "woman).  The client should know as *little* about the class instance as possible - just enough to do it's job; no more.

Finally, if "man" and "woman" do the same operation, but need to do it *differently* ... that's where virtual methods come in.

These links might help:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/
- http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/122-virtual-functions/

Comment: I know all the tutorials. but what if woman and man not only have the same methods with different "actions", what if woman needs an additional mehtod.

Answer (score 2):

You do it like this:

```
switch (human->gender) {
   case GenderMan: 
      doTheManlyThing((Man*)human);
      break;
   case GenderWoman: 
      doTheWomanlyThing((Woman*)human);
      break;
   default:
      abort("Unknown gender, stop the world");
}
```

C-compliant syntax is used intentionally. If you're going to do this like we used to back when, why not go for the full monty?

If you use `typeid(*human)` instead of the integral type indicator, or `if (dynamic_cast<whatewer*>) ...` like today's kids do, it's the very same thing conceptually, only somewhat (or a lot) slower.

The alternative is of course

```
human->doTheHumanThing();   // a call to  a virtual function
                            // possibly with an empty body
                            // in case one of the genders 
                            // "has more actions" than the other(s)
```

but Real Programmers Don't Use Virtual Functions. They switch on type IDs, and they *like it*.

Another alternative is the Visitor Pattern, which is again a bunch of virtual functions, only laid horizontally instead of vertically, so to speak. I don't want this answer to become 11521273th description of Visitor, so I will just refer you to [the universal font of wisdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: would be a good solution, but i'm using a predefined function which only accepts something like "creatueres" as object which would be a parent of humans. Now I need to know whether or not the the creature is a human.

Comment: Perhaps someone might have missed the point, so I will spell it out, just in case. **THIS IS ACTUALLY NOT A GOOD SOLUTION**.

Comment: I've seen such a solution in several Game programming books :>

Comment: but in bigger project this will be a too large switch

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself paralyzed by analysis, remember the rule of **premature optimization** (ie. don't do it). Just get on with it. You can choose the other path later down the road (just don't wait too long). :)

> In each post, I read that dynamic_cast comes with a cost. I didn't
>   tested it –

There is a simple solution to this type of worry, and it is a basic skillset of programming: *Test it yourself.*

Regarding your worry (in comments) about performance of RTTI/dynamic_cast performance: also apply the rule of **premature optimization**. Virtual function calls are so relatively fast that you shouldn't care, unless you have observed a problem. Unless you have proof of a performance problem, do you actually have a performance problem? Bjarne Stroustrup mentions in one of his C++ books the doubt people had about performance of virtual dispatch. Nowadays, tests show 50,000,000 virtual dispatch calls take less than a second. In my profiling, a virtual call is almost identical in performance to a non-virtual call. The overhead is statistical noise (in all but the rarest cases).

With today's processors and cache architectures, combined with the smart C++ compilers, we should stop worrying about the overhead of virtual dispatch or RTTI. On my PC I can test a vector of 50,000,000 objects with dynamic_cast<> in under a second, and that includes the if statement and another instruction per branch path.

```
   // populate vector
   std::vector<A*> avec;
   for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
      if (i %  2)
         avec.push_back(new A());
      else
         avec.push_back(new B());
   }

   clock_t begin = clock();

   int j = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++) {
      if (dynamic_cast<B*>(avec[i])) {
         j += 1;
      }
      else
         j -= 1;
   }

   clock_t end = clock();
   double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   cout << "dynamic_cast: " << elapsed_secs << std::endl;
   cout << "j=" << j << std::endl;
```

PS: If you try this code, I recommend using a smaller vector and just re-iterating multiple times. I actually compiled and ran as an x64 project, but the point is NOT to allocate a 50million item vector, the point is to show virtual dispatch across a bunch of random object pointers. For 32-bit it will likely generate an out of memory error.

If C++ virtual dispatch is too slow for your purpose, then you are probably going to care less about elegant Object Oriented design, and more about tweaking every last cycle. In that case, drop the virtual functions, make extensive use of inline functions, or write in non-object oriented C or assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found another solution.
The framework I'm using actually provides a solution for this.
if(object->GetClass()->IsChildOf(APlayerCharacter::StaticClass()))

This actually helps me a lot!